# Advantages to developers of knowing that user will have Google Maps pre-installed

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

I'm researching the legal effects of Google's mandatory "all-or-nothing" requirement i.e. if the OEM wants to pre-install Google Search on their Android phones, they also have to take Youtube, Google Maps, Hangouts etc.

I am arguing that, from the developer's perspective, there are great advantages to having the pre-installed suite of apps all come from the same provider (i.e. Google), rather than letting OEMs cherry pick different apps for the pre-installed suite (for example, Bing Search, Google Maps, Skype, etc.)

I'd like to know whether *knowing that Google Maps* will be pre-installed on an Android phone makes life easier for developers that need to either a) embed a map in their app or b) link to a map.

For example, does the Geo Intent link only to Google Maps? Or, if the user has installed another 3rd party maps app on their phone and set it to default, will it link the user to that app instead?

If the developer couldn't be sure that the user has Google Maps, would they have to include more burdensome code in order to account for the fact that their link will need to open a different maps app?

Anything ideas would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of this "question" is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

> does the Geo Intent link only to Google Maps?

No. Any application is welcome to support the `geo:` scheme and related paths.

> if the user has installed another 3rd party maps app on their phone and set it to default, will it link the user to that app instead?

That depends on whether the other app supports the `geo:` scheme and related paths.

> If the developer couldn't be sure that the user has Google Maps, would they have to include more burdensome code in order to account for the fact that their link will need to open a different maps app?

Not usually, any more than a developer wishing to allow the user to view a PDF document needs to "include more burdensome code in order to account for the fact that their link will need to open a different" PDF viewer than whatever one they had been thinking of a the time that they wrote that code.

Developers that rely upon *undocumented and unsupported* `Uri` structures, expecting Google Maps to always handle them because the current version does, will run into bigger problems. They might run into bigger problems with Google Maps itself, if the developers of that app elect to discontinue support for those undocumented and unsupported structures. And various third-party map applications might not support those structures either.